# vim does not reload "set <option>" config in .vimrc

Tags: vim

In my `.vimrc` I have this: `set relativenumber`. If I comment that line or event if I set `set norelativenumber` and restart vim the changes do not get applied. But if I run the same `set norelativenumber` command in a running instance of vim, not only does it work, but it also persists across restarts.

I can confirm that my `.vimrc` is loaded, it just seems that the settings get ignored.

Comment: can it be reproduced when you re/start your vim with `--noplugin` ?

Comment: @Kent running with `--noplugin` was the same but I solved the issue, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had this in my `.vimrc` which saves folds:

```
autocmd BufWinLeave * silent! mkview
autocmd BufWinEnter * silent! loadview
```

`mkview` also saves vim options. Adding the following line resolves the issue:

```
set viewoptions-=options
```